# Using a particle with a bit more complex hierarchy?

Tags: particles

I've got an parent object which I want to use as a particle and this object has children/other particle systems on it etc. However when I try it to use it as a particle system it only creates duplicates of the parent. How do I fix this? I do not want to join everything into a single mesh.

Comment: make it a group and make particles from that group?

Comment: Does this help? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27818/is-it-possible-to-recursively-instance-object-particles/27834#27834

Comment: @Jerryno This still treats the parts separately and the particles dont seem to show up either.

Comment: @RayMairlot It does to an extent. But the particle instance modifier doesnt seem to take into account children objects.

Comment: then is everything on the same layer? If not it won't show up in preview, only should work in render.

Comment: @Jerryno Yes everything was on the same layer. But I finally got the result I wanted using a combination of the mentioned methods. Thanks.

Comment: In more recent versions you can use a collection and then you select the option for all of it on each instance instead of randomly from the collection.