# Recursive Particle system

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, particles

I have a blue Suzanne. On that it should emit red balls. And on each red ball it should emit green box. 
[image]

I have tried with [Is it possible to recursively instance object particles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27818/is-it-possible-to-recursively-instance-object-particles)

But it does not really answer the question nor work and also does not work on animated objects. Or I am wrong in sequence.

No green boxes available in result:
[image: How it looks now]

Download current file: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=AD9FE0A4134005AA!2480433&authkey=!ALz-h9Vlfrbekfs&ithint=file%2cblend

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer is actually quite simple: this cannot work in current design - to simplify, objects as particles are not actual objects, but instances of objects, with quite limited sub-set of objects features. An instance cannot emit particles.