# Particle (hair) issue

Tags: particles, hair

It's really complicated for me to describe this situation, but I'll try my best.

When I applied particles on my drupelet[image] everything seems to work fine.

Then when I try to use the drupelet as a particle on the other object it doesn't have any hair particles[image]. Can anyone explain what am I doing wrong?

Tank you soo much kind people for your time and effort to explain everything!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27818/is-it-possible-to-recursively-instance-object-particles