# Blender particle system , emitting a mesh with a particle system

Tags: system

I made a simple flower and i used the particle system for the petels , now im trying to use the particle system on my plane to emmit the flower but its rendering as a mesh without the petels , is there a way to fix that?

Comment: You would need to use the "Particle Instance" Modifier. Does this help ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/27818/86891