# Particle Instance Modifier - Options to Offset missing in V2.83

Tags: modifiers, particles, interface

[image][image]In Blender 2.83 I cannot find the Options in the Particle Instance Modifier that include 'Amount' and 'Offset'. They are shown under the World properties in previous versions.
I need this control to avoid overlapping of systems in vertex groups.

Answer (score 0):

These settings are available in the modifier panel in my build.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I've seen this panel in the manual but I cannot find it in my build v2.83

Comment: Have you downloaded the latest version ? https://www.blender.org/download/ Or are you talking about the panel where you add the modifier ? It is located in the properties workspace, and is identified with a blue wrench icon when an object is selected

Comment: I have downloaded the latest version (not the experimental one) and that panel is not there. Under the modifier tab (blue wrench) itsimply refers to the particle system tab and in the particle system tab those options do not appear.

Comment: Oh, okay I see. You added a "Particle Systems" modifier, but what you are looking for is a "Particle Instance" modifier, it is a different one. It is located on the row just top of the particle system modifier when you click on "Add Modifier"

Comment: I really appreciate you trying to help me. How can I add a screen shot here to show you that it does not appear?

Comment: I have added an image to the post.

Comment: No problem we will work this out ! Again, this is not the right modifier. Delete the particle system by going into the tab with particles (right below the blue wrench) and click on the minus icon. This should get rid of the modifier. Then go back to the blue wrench icon tab (the modifier tab) and add a particle **instance** modifier, not a particle **system**, by clicking on the button that expands a list

Comment: Gorgious,

Following your advice, I removed the two Particle Systems, then introduced the Modifier - Particle Instance, setting both Amount and Offset firstly to 1.
Of course, no effects appear on the object presumably because there is nothing to make an instance of. Also in this modifier there is no way to apply the insatnce to a vertex group.
I then added two particle systems, Hair - Black and Hair - White and assigned them to their appropriate vertex groups. You can see the render result in the post, clearly showing the overlap that I want to avoid.
Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the particle instance modifier properly ? You are supposed to use it on a different object than the one with the particle system modifier. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/simulate/particle_instance.html

Comment: I'm not sure of anything. I don't understand how I can use another object when I only have one object. Maybe you could point me to a tutorial? It seems such a simple thing I want to do i.e. prevent overlap. I originally followed the Add Quick Fur effect and the only problem was the overlap at adjoining vertex groups.

Comment: This thread should help you https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27818/is-it-possible-to-recursively-instance-object-particles and maybe this one too https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5961/how-can-particles-be-emitted-from-particles

Comment: Thank you these look interesting and I will study them.